# Is there any way to determine if two events were triggered due to the same action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick, onchange

Due to the order of events on different elements of a form (see http://jsfiddle.net/fs7norbL/, obligatory code at bottom), I need to handle both the onchange and onclick event of a checkbox.

I want to know if a checkbox onchange and onclick event both happened due to the same human interaction or not. I may only handle one of them (whichever comes first) for each human interaction but need to be able to handle both event types.

event.timestamp won't do due to this long standing open mozilla bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=238041 .
There doesn't seem to be anything else in the event that I can use.

How to determine whether two events were caused by the same human interaction.

---

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
```

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
    console.log('checkbox click');
});

$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    console.log('checkbox change');
});

$('form').change(function() {
    console.log('form change');
});
```

Comment: Is  `onchange` not triggered when user clicks the checkbox? It causes the checkbox to change it's state, so the change event happens.

I think you my delete `onlick` listener.

Comment: @zmii `onchange` is not triggered for keyboard-triggered changes (select input, press spacebar) on all browsers. `onclick` is the only event that reliable triggers on all possible human actions, so `onclick` cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You may trigger the `change` event in the `click` handler -> delegate the callback to one function with some message ( or add local variable with state reachable from `click` and `change` handers).

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
    console.log('checkbox clicked');
    this.change();
});
```

Thus you'll know when what happened.

Comment: That doesn't prevent the `onchange` events being triggered before the checkbox `onclick` on Chrome.